# Android SQLITE search VS ArrayList search for small amount of dataset

Tags: android, sqlite, search, optimization, arraylist

Suppose, In my app I have a sqlite table that can contain at most 20 row. Each row has 2 column(id, name). Where I frequently need to search by Id to get Name. For this frequent need I have two solution:

**Solution 1:**  Get rows in a `arraylist<model>` and then find name from array.

**Solution 2:** Every time search on sqlite table.

Now please give your opinion which one is better? 
Remember again, I need this search in my recycleView item, so it call so frequently.

**Thanks**

Comment: Are you displaying all 20 data in recyclerview?

Comment: No. I have a endless recycleView. And on each item of that recycleview need Name by Id from this 20 dataset table. @AjayShrestha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get what is your real intent, but if your task is to search by id often, I would use

```
LongSparseArray<String> idsToNames; // or LongSparseArray<Model>
```

Which will map primitive long to Strings in a more memory-efficient way than `Map` and will have a better performance than `ArrayList` when searching.

The advantage over querying SQLite here is that you can do it in a blocking manner instead of having to query database on a background thread every time the lookup runs.

The disadvantage is that whenever data changes in SQLite, you will have to rebuild your idsToNames map. Also, if the number of entries in SQLite will eventually grow, you will end up in a large collection. So I would recommend this approach only if the updates to the database during this session will not happen, and if the data size is always predictable or fixed.

Comment: Data size is fixed. So LongSparseArray is better than SQLITE query for this context?

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan if you said you will search very often, then I would say yes. But what's your real task? If your real task is, for example, opening a details screen, I would go for passing id to details screen and loading the model there.

Comment: Yes, It's only a view screen by endless recycleview where each Item need to show Name by Id.
 And Thanks a lot for your valuable answer. :)

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan "endless recycleview"? for just 20 items?

Comment: Not actually! Endless recycleview on a large table. But I get only id from that large table. For that I need to convert Id to Name from this 20 items Table. @pskink

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan so when your data comes from sqlite query why dont you use a `Cursor` based adapter (similar to `CursorAdapter` for a "normal" `ListVieew`)?

Comment: @pskink I didn't know about this. Now I am trying to know this. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan see https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: Ok. Thanks @pskink